# Resolve &amp issue in URL

Tags: javascript

Hi I am using following code in Javascript:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.parent.location='https://c.cs15.visual.force.com/apex/ProtocolPage?govid={{>NCT_Id__c}}&address={!latVal},{!longVal}&zip={!zipCode}';return false">{{>Title__c}}</a>
```

When I view page, `&` is replaced by `&amp`. I want to get original value that is only `&`.

Comment: Are you able to place javascript on the page that will be the new URL?

Comment: If you are not able to place javascript on the destination page, could a PHP page be used which takes the encodeURI and redirects the browser to the page with a decodeURI?

Answer (score -1):

Just check this :

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_decodeuri

The testable example has some defined functions that may be the solution.

```
var uri = "my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab";
var enc = encodeURI(uri); /* changes the & to &amp; */
var dec = decodeURI(enc); /* change the &amp; to & */
```